# "The network name cannot be found" exception in ClickOnce deployment?

Tags: c#, clickonce

I'm getting the following exception when I try to install a ClickOnce application:

```
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of C:\Users\user\Downloads\appname.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading file://192.168.2.9/appdir/appname.application did not succeed.
    + The network name cannot be found.

    + The network name cannot be found.

    + The network name cannot be found.
```

I haven't been able to figure it out.  I've tried looking around on the net and there don't seem to be any resources on the issue. Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: is this a file from your home network..? if so what is the name of the machine that you are trying to download the file..? it may also help to show the code where you are getting this error..`if this is a file that's on your LAN then why not just use a normal File.Copy Method..???`

Comment: @DJKRAZE  There's no code, the exception is being thrown by the ClickOnce launcher.  I've tried using both the hostname and the IP.

Comment: Who has or owns the source code for the .msi.. did you write it..?

Comment: There's no MSI.  It's just a standard ClickOnce deployment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the installation URL in the publish settings.  Rather than using a web path, I was using a share for the path. The actual location was set up in IIS, so of course the file could not be found at the share.

Changing the field "Installation Folder URL" from:

`\\\server-name\path`

to

`http://server-name/path`

resolved the problem.  Silly mistake.

Comment: I had the same problem. I confirmed that the dialogs indicate that a UNC is allowed. The issue is caused by spaces in the path. The wizard correctly tries to encode any spaces to %20, prefixing the "url" with file: and converting forward slashes to backslashes, but it still doesn't work. In the end, removing the spaces in the path (deploying to and installing from a different path with no spaces) worked for me. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue in this way. Check the Permission in both IIS AND Folder

```
Give the IIS Full control Permision to Everyone
Share the physical path folder to Everyone
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly these kind of error messages are due to wrong connection string that cannot be found over network. Rechecking the Datasource value or server value and and database name in connection string will solve the problem